# Radioactive Decay Function

Tags: calculus

A new radioactive element has been discovered, Bevonium, which has a half-life of $130$ years.

A sample of Bevonium has been unearthed which is $85$% of its original amount.

How old is the sample?

I set up $$A= A_0 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{t/h}$$

with $\frac{A}{A_o}=0.85$ and got $30.48$ years.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: How did you get 30.48. How did you check your answer.

Comment: A/(A_o)=.85=(1/2)^(t/h). log_1/2(.85)=log_1/2(1/2^(t/h))=t/h                                       log_1/2(.85)=log(.85/.5)=t/h=t/130                                                          130*(log(.85/.5)=t=30.48 years

Comment: 130*(log(.85/.5))=t=30.48 years

Comment: It looks like the 30.48 years is *correct*. But the last expression should have been $t=130\frac{\ln0.85}{\ln0.5}$.

Comment: You can check using the decay formula N(t)=N_o x e^(-0.693*t/130) and arrive at the same answer. Again, .85=N(t)/N_o

Comment: But remember ln(0.85)/ln(0.5)=log(0.85)/log(0.5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Half life is the time radioactive stuff takes until its half decay, it takes 130 to do so, $\frac{A_0}{A} = 0.85 = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{t}{h}}$ so $\frac{t}{h} = \log_{\frac{1}{2}}(0.85) $ so $t = 30.48$, this is basically what you already said, Nothing wrong about it !, already 85% is left not gone .